# Problema de formato de tikets c#

Tags: c#, impresión

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo un problema al imprimir el tiket en una impresora. como pueden ver la hoja es tamaño carta, por lo cual la impresora me marca error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

lo que no entiendo es como ajustar la hoja para que se pueda imprimir a la medida de la impresora.

> Codigo C#

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PrintDialog printDialog = new PrintDialog();
        PrintDocument printDocument = new PrintDocument();
        printDialog.Document = printDocument; //add the document to the dialog box...      
        printDocument.PrintPage += new System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventHandler(CreateReceipt); //add an event handler that will do the printing

        //on a till you will not want to ask the user where to print but this is fine for the test envoironment.

        DialogResult result = printDialog.ShowDialog();

        if (result == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            printDocument.Print();

        }
    }

    public void CreateReceipt(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {

        PrinterSettings ps = new PrinterSettings();
        ps.PrinterName = "Brother QL-720NW"; //Para cargar las propiedades de la impresora en ps
        e.PageSettings.PaperSize = ps.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize;

        Graphics graphic = e.Graphics;

        Font font = new Font("Courier New", 12); //must use a mono spaced font as the spaces need to line up
        float fontHeight = font.GetHeight();

        int startX = 10;
        int startY = 10;
        int offset = 40;



        graphic.DrawString("AdminEmpaq", new Font("Courier New", 18), new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX, startY);
        string top = "Codigo Entrada: ".PadRight(10) + "1340";
        graphic.DrawString(top, font, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX, startY + offset);
        offset = offset + (int)fontHeight; //make the spacing consistent
        graphic.DrawString("----------------------------------", font, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX, startY + offset);
        offset = offset + (int)fontHeight + 5; //make the spacing consistent

        offset = offset + 5; //make some room so that the total stands out.
        graphic.DrawString("Proveedor: ".PadRight(5) + String.Format("{0:c}", "Manuel Morales Ochoa"), font, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX, startY + offset);
        offset = offset + 15;
        graphic.DrawString("Peso: ".PadRight(5) + String.Format("{0:c}", "1780"), font, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX, startY + offset);
        offset = offset + 15;
        graphic.DrawString("Cajas: ".PadRight(5) + String.Format("{0:c}", "20"), font, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX, startY + offset);
        offset = offset + 15;
        graphic.DrawString("Tara: ".PadRight(5) + String.Format("{0:c}", "3"), font, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX, startY + offset);
        offset = offset + 15;
        graphic.DrawString("Peso Neto: ".PadRight(5) + String.Format("{0:c}", "1777"), new Font("Courier New", 12, FontStyle.Bold), new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX, startY + offset);

        offset = offset + 30; //make some room so that the total stands out.
        graphic.DrawString("     Thank-you for your custom,", font, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX, startY + offset);
        offset = offset + 15;
        graphic.DrawString("       please come back soon!", font, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX, startY + offset);

    }
}
```

> Como evitar que salga la ventana de seleccion de impresora y se valla directamente?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola Manuel, no pongas el codigo en un enlace aparte, ponlo aqui. Para formatearlo puedes seleccionarlo y pulsar `ctrl+k` o el boton `{}`. Intenta poner solo el codigo referente a este problema y mostrarnos qué intentaste para resolverlo y que errores te dio. Mira [ask] para más informacion. Un saludo

Comment: Has probado usando la propiedad [`PageSettings.PaperSize`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.drawing.printing.pagesettings.papersize(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes establecer el `PaperSize` de la impresora por la que imprimes en el `PrintPageEventArgs` de la siguiente manera:

```
public void CreateReceipt(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    PrinterSettings ps = new PrinterSettings();
    ps.PrinterName = "Nombre de la impresora"; //Para cargar las propiedades de la impresora en ps

    e.PageSettings.PaperSize = ps.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize;

    ...

}
```

**EDIT**

Si la impresora la tienes como impresora por defecto, para obtenerla puedes añadir esto:

```
PrinterSettings ps = new PrinterSettings();

foreach (PrinterSettings ps2 in PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters)
{
    if (ps.IsDefaultPrinter)
    {
        ps = ps2;
        break;
    }
}

e.PageSettings.PaperSize = ps.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize;
```

De esta manera te aseguras de que estas cogiendo los datos de la impresora por defecto del sistema.

---

Para evitar que salga la ventana de impresión, debes quitar el `PrintDialog` del evento `button1_Click` y quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PrintDocument printDocument = new PrintDocument();

    printDocument.PrintPage += new System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventHandler(CreateReceipt); //add an event handler that will do the printing

    printDocument.Print();
}
```

Comment: me sigue marcando el mismo aviso,el papel que uso es de 62mm x 8m, hay alguna propiedad donde establecer eso?

Comment: @ManuelMorales supongo que no has mirado el enlace que te puse. Probablemente tendras que mirar en la coleccion `PrinterSettings.PaperSizes` y buscar la que corresponda con la impresora. Tal vez tambien tengas que ajustar `PaperSource` ..

Comment: @ManuelMorales Revisa las propiedades de la impresora a ver que tamaño tiene, si lo tiene mal ponlo bien y prueba de nuevo

Comment: Ya he resuelto lo de impresion con lo que ha dicho @Marc, ahora solo quiero que no aparezca la ventana de seleccion de impresión y se valla directamente a impresora predeterminada. he adjuntado una imagen.

Comment: @ManuelMorales He editado la respuesta poniendo la solución a lo otro.

Comment: Excelente @Marc, saludos!